# How to wait promise solved afterthen render in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, promise

I got this error when using promise:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I'm pretty sure this error is got from my promise async request, when i not using promise it working fine.
But when im using promise to handle async request, i got this error, i need promise to handle it, so how can i fix this?

This is my Async Request.

```js
export const LoginAPI = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/login/', body, config)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
        SwalAlert('Successfully Login...', 'Welcome To 7Blankpages...', 'success');
        resolve(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAILED });
        if (err.response.data.non_field_errors) SwalAlert('Oops...', `${err.response.data.non_field_errors}`, 'error');
        reject(false);
      });
  });
  return promise;
};
```

This is my Login Handling

```js
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await LoginUser(username, password).catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
    if (response) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setUsername('');
      setPassword('');
    }
  };

  if (auth.isAuthenticated && auth.user.is_active) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
```

Comment: what is LoginUser ? you provided code for LoginAPI...

Comment: i changed LoginAPI to LoginUser when mapping dispatch to props(Redux)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happened because your handlesubmit function is asynchronous that makes if block to get executed redirecting to url '/' changing the component. but the function setisloading,setusername etc in your handlesubmit will still be excecuting which led to memory leak.  To prevent this add useEffect hook with cleanup function.

```
useEffect(()=>{

  //cleanup function
  return ()=>{
     setisloading(false);
     setusername('');
     setpassword('');
    }
     })
```

Comment: oh greats!,it solved like i want! ,thankyou so much for helping me,have a nice day!